# How to show 6 more rows and hide the previous 5 rows of a table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to only display the first 6 rows of the table and when I press a button, the previous six will be hidden and the next six will be shown.

Here is my javascript that shows the first 6 tables:

```
function setInnerHTML(){
<%
    ArrayList userBoxList = BoxList.getInstance().getUserBoxList();

    if(userBoxList.size()>6){%>
        document.getElementById('down').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('page').value = counter + 1;
        <% size = 6;
    }
    else{
        size = userBoxList.size();
    } 

    for(x=0; x < size; x++)
    {
        UserBox box = (UserBox) userBoxList.get(x); %>  
        document.getElementById(origID).onclick = changeColor;

        var items = document.getElementById(origID).getElementsByTagName("td");
        items[0].innerHTML = "<%=box.getInfo().getBoxNumber()%>";
        items[1].innerHTML = "<%=box.getInfo().getBoxName()%>";
        items[2].innerHTML = "<%=box.getInfo().getOwnerUserName()%>";
        items[3].innerHTML = "<%=box.getInfo().getCurrentSize()%>" + "MB"; 

        origID++;

    <%}
%>
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<tr style="height:40px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="0">
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:40px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="1">
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:40px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="2">
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:40px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="3">
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:40px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="4">
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:40px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="5">
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
    <td align="left"> </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating the table dynamically just using

```
> document.getElementById.style.display = "table-row" and 
> document.getElementById.style.display = "none"
```

to hide and show the TR.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to mix logic with view. Try to use already existing components to display table.
You could choose displayTag: http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/ or datatables https://datatables.net/ or many others.
Use server side processing with ajax call to display next records.